# Attaching method to schema in Node not being called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using a password verification based on this demo http://devsmash.com/blog/password-authentication-with-mongoose-and-bcrypt and for some reason the method is not attaching to my 'user' return, resulting in an error

Here is my code...

```
module.exports = function (app, mongoose, config, passport) {
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
    var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;


    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        email: {
            type:String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }
    });

    var _User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

    // Bcrypt middleware

    UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
        var user = this;

        if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

        bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
            if(err) return next(err);

            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if(err) return next(err);
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    });


    // Password verification
    UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err) return cb(err);
            cb(null, isMatch);
        });
    };



    return {
        User : _User,


        isValidUserPassword : function(auth, done) {
            _User.findOne({email : auth.body.username}, function(err, user){
                // if(err) throw err;
                if(err) return done(err);
                if(!user) return done(null, false, { message : 'Incorrect email.' });

                user.comparePassword(auth.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Password123:', isMatch); // -> Password123: true
                });

            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it calls

```
var _User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

before defining the `UserSchema.pre` hook and `UserSchema.methods.comparePassword` method.

Call `mongoose.model` after defining your schema and things will work:

```
// Bcrypt middleware

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});


// Password verification
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

var _User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```